using PCA to filter outliers in MATLAB
A bit of a silly question (I suspect). I am using MATLAB to preprocess some bulk RNAseq data. I am calling PCA on my normalized counts just as an initial way to identify outliers I didn't automatically reject. There are indeed some clear outliers but I am not sure how to use the score matrix output by pca to filter my original data because it is now in descending order of explained variance. How can I use the pca scores to return to the indicies of problematic samples. Thank you so much! Info below:
[coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained] = pca(normCounts');

size(normCounts) 136 samples with 24427 measured genes

ans =

       24427         136


The idea in itself is not wrong, though removing outliers before PCA would be better in my eyes, since outliers might significantly affect the computation of the decomposition. In Matlab, there are many outlier detection functions, have you tried them? Also number of variables is a lot higher than the number of records, this might lead to some problems as well... Though I am not familiar with biotech statistics so take my comment with a grain of salt

Hi, I do remove outliers prior to this step and my axes are flipped here hence why I transpose the matrix prior to running PCA :)

so you would like to remove outliers after PCA, where you already removed outliers before the PCA steps? I think it's not really necessary. You can still do it, try to identify the outliers first and see if you can get some
